# Цикл <c:choose> в JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

Имеется jsp страница, вызываемая двумя параметрами action(одна на оба параметра).
Внутри нее хочу сделать два разных блока, в зависимости от пришедшего в адресную строку action - затем изменить его и совершить определенное действие(последние действия уже в сервлете, работают как надо)

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<jsp:include page="fragments/header.jsp"/>
<section>
    <form>
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="<%=request.getParameter("action").equals("submitClear")%>">
                <h1>Вы действительно желаете удалить все резюме? Отменить операцию будет невозможно!</h1>
                <button name="action" type="submit" value="clear">Подтвердить удаление</button>
            </c:when>

            <c:when test="<%=request.getParameter("action").equals("submitDelete")%>">
                <h1>Вы действительно желаете удалить это резюме? Отменить операцию будет невозможно!</h1>
                <button name="action" type="submit" value="delete">Подтвердить удаление</button>
            </c:when>
            <button type="reset" onclick="window.history.back()">Отменить</button>
        </c:choose>
    </form>
</section>
<jsp:include page="fragments/footer.jsp"/>
</body>
</html>
```

На текущий момент у меня 500 ошибка со следующим содержимым:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/jsp/clear.jsp (line: [13], column: [23]) Attribute value [request.getParameter("action").equals("submitClear")] is quoted with ["] which must be escaped when used within the value
```

Подскажите - как исправить?

Answer (score 0):

```
<c:when test="${param.action == 'submitClear' }">
```

2019-й год на дворе, не надо использовать скриптлеты.

Comment: Как задать изменение этого параметра при срабатывании when, чтобы затем использовать его внутри button?

Comment: @MaksimRybalkin лучше использовать `<c:set>` для задания значения переменной в контексте и использовать в button её.